# Passing a 2D Array into Function in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:-

```
void display(int *p)
{ 
 printf ("%u\n", p);
 printf ("%u\n", p+1);
}

int main()
{
  int a[3][4] = {
                  1,2,3,4,
                  5,6,7,8,
                  9,0,1,2
                };
  printf("%u\n",a);
  printf("%u\n",a+1);
  display(a);


}
```

Why do a+1 and p+1 give different addresses? If a and p give the same addresses, then shouldn't a+1 and p+1 be pointing to same addresses?

Comment: Given that you ignore the compilation warnings, you should get a difference of `sizeof(int)` (probably 4) from `display()` and you should get a difference of `4*sizeof(int)` (probably 16) from the code in `main()`.  This is because `a` in `a+1` is of type `int (*)[4]` or pointer to array of 4 `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler should have thrown an error (or at least a warning) when you were passing `a` which is of type `int (*)[4]` to a function that expected an `int *`. You would see this if you turned on all compiler warnings.

My compiler clearly states:

> > Warning: passing argument 1 of 'display' from incompatible pointer type

Word of advice: when your compiler complains about your code, you would do well to heed it. Learn to use ALL compiler flags (`-Wall -pedantic` etc) - this will catch most bad coding habits before they become ingrained. Or one day they will bite you.

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 says: `note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[4]’`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I have an old compiler; the new error message is clearly more descriptive. The basic message is the same...

Comment: Almost the same - the detailed type is different (pointer to array of 4 `int` is different from pointer to pointer to `int`).

Comment: I see your point now - have edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They have different sizes, so moving to the next one adds a different amount. The same thing would occur if you used an `int` pointer and a `char` pointer -- since they have different sizes, adding one to the same address will give you different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For the code to compile, you've to change the last statement to `display(&a[0][0])`. Reason is [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/183120) is not applied repeatedly, so `int[3][4]` becomes `int(*)[4]`. Once you make the code compilable, you'll see the problem you've asked about: increment by 1 showing different values for pointers `a` and `p`.

Although the actual value of both `a` and `p` would be the same base address of the array / first value location (call it X), it is to be noted that both pointers are of different types; `p` is of type `int*`, while `int (*) [4]` would be the type of the pointer to the 2-dimensional array (as array decay applies only to the first dimension. In pseudocode

> p + 1 = X + sizeof(int)
>
> a + 1 = X + sizeof(int (*) [4]) = X + (sizeof(int) * 4)

where 4 is the second dimension of the array. Hence, on a machine where `sizeof(int)` is 4, you'd see `X + 4` for `p` and `X + 16` for `a`. On my machine, `p + 1` = 0x22fe34, while `a + 1` = 0x22fe40.